# Struggling to Derive First-Order Condition in Lucas (2004) on Optimal Control

Tags: calculus-of-variations, economics, optimal-control, hamiltonian-path, dynamic-programming

I am reading Robert Lucas (2004), *Life Earnings and Rural-Urban Migration,* and I came across a rather peculiar optimal control problem that I'd like to ask about. Thank you!

The objective function is
$
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\int_0^t r(s)\, ds\right) \cdot h(t) \cdot u(t) dt
$

The constraints are
$
\frac{dh(t)}{dt} = \delta \cdot h(t) \cdot (1 - u(t)), \quad 0 < u(t) < 1
$

The first-order condition provided in the article (Equation 4 in the paper) is
$
h(t) = \delta \int_t^\infty \exp\left(-\int_t^\tau r(s)\, ds\right) \cdot h(\tau) \cdot u(\tau)\, d\tau
$

However, I cannot derive this result myself. Here's my approach:

I constructed the Hamiltonian
$H = \exp\left(-\int_0^t r(s)\, ds\right) \cdot h(t) \cdot u(t) + \lambda \cdot \delta \cdot h(t) \cdot (1 - u(t)) .
$

Setting $ \frac{\partial H}{\partial u} = 0 $, I obtain

$
\exp\left(-\int_0^t r(s)\, ds\right) \cdot h(t) = \lambda \cdot \delta \cdot h(t)
$

After simplification, this yields
$
\exp\left(-\int_0^t r(s)\, ds\right) = \lambda \cdot \delta, \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda(0) = \frac{1}{\delta}
$

I then have $ \frac{d\lambda}{dt} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial h} = -\left( \exp\left(-\int_0^t r(s)\, ds\right) \cdot u + \lambda \cdot \delta \cdot (1-u(t)) \right) $.

Substituting the above equations, I get
$
\frac{d\lambda}{dt} = -\lambda \cdot \delta
$

With the initial value for $ \lambda $, this leads to
$
\lambda(t) = \frac{1}{\delta} \cdot \exp(-\delta \cdot t)
$

However, I am stuck at this point as there seems to be no further conditions involving $ h(t) $ and $ u(t) $. How is the first-order condition in the paper derived? Could anyone provide some guidance? Thank you!